# Lua attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'amount' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

when I try to use script function this error appears:

```
attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'amount' (a nil value)
```

this is the function:

```
<>
function openAdvertisements( player, command )
    local advertisements = { } --These will hold our advertisements to send to the client and populate our advertisement tables.

    if not player then player = source end

    --Fetch all of the advertisements from the database --mysql:query("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1")
    for _, ad in ipairs( call(getResourceFromName("mysql"), "query_free", "UPDATE `accounts` SET `dm`=`dm`-".. amount*2000 .." WHERE `id`=".. tostring(gameAccountID)  .."")  ) do
        if tonumber( ad.expiry ) >= tonumber( getRealTime().timestamp ) then --Check if the advertisement has expired, delete it if so.
            ad.author = exports.mysql:select_one( "characters", { id = ad.created_by } ).charactername
            table.insert( advertisements, ad )
        else
            deleteAdvertisement( ad.id )
        end
    end

    triggerClientEvent( player, resourceName .. ":display_all", root, advertisements, exports.integration:isPlayerAdmin( player ) ) --Send the advertisements to the client to create the GUI.
end
```

ERROR concerns this line:

```
for _, ad in ipairs( call(getResourceFromName("mysql"), "query_free", "UPDATE `accounts` SET `dm`=`dm`-".. amount*2000 .." WHERE `id`=".. tostring(gameAccountID)  .."")  ) do
```

Comment: The variable `amount` does not have a value, so it is `nil`, and trying to calculate `nil*2000` results in an error because `nil` is not a number and not a string convertible to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined local `amount` variable, so lua looks for it in global table (`_ENV` or `_G`, depending on lua version), where it doesn't exsist too (`nil` for non-existing key).

Lua tries to exectue `nil*2000`, which leads to that error.

Comment: I found a similar topic and they say, that I have to change this 
           call(getResourceFromName("mysql"), "query_free", "UPDATE `accounts` SET `dm`=`dm`-".. amount*2000 .." WHERE `id`=".. tostring(gameAccountID)  .."")                      to this mysql:query("SELECT * FROM 'advertisements' WHERE 1") but now i have another error attempt to index global 'mysql' (a nil value)